# Importing Values from a Properties File for Automation Testing

Tags: java, eclipse, automation, testng

I have to write a test that can print a value from a properties file using a dataprovider in TestNG. I am unsure where to begin. I have already completed the task using hardcoded values but cannot figure out to do so using the file. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class ConfigurationProvider {

    @DataProvider(name = "browserProvider")
    public FileInputStream getFile() throws IOException {
        
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                "C:\\Users\\user\\git\\practice\\automation\\src\\test\\resources\\config.properties");
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(fis);
        p.getProperty("BrowserType");
                
        return fis;
    }
    
    @Test(dataProvider = "browserProvider")
    public void canPrintBrowser(String browserType) {
        System.out.println("The browser type is: " + browserType); 
    }
}
```

properties file looks like this:

```
Url=http://the-internet.herokuapp.com
BrowserType=chrome
ImplicitTimeout=5000
ScriptTimeout=5000
```

Running the test fails because it wants me to use `Object[][]`. But I am unsure how to fit it in. All the research I've done so far is just over complicated stuff using webdrivers etc... This should be basic but I'm new to this and it's really racking my brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataProvider` requieres an `Object[][]` because that will be the two dimension array with the parameters of all executions of the `@Test` that uses that `DataProvider`.

For instance, if the `Object[][]` returned is this:

```
      data[0][0] = "Peter"; 
      data[0][1] = "18"; 

     data[1][0] = "Ross"; 
     data[1][1] = "45"; 

     data[2][0] = "Diana"; 
     data[2][1] = "11";
```

The `@Test` method, which must then be defined with 2 parameters, will be executed 3 times. The first one with the patameters `Peter` and `18`, the second one with `Ross` and `45`, and so on.

That is how a `DataProvider` works. So you will have to manually parse the `properties` file and with ots contents build the `Object[][]` that will serve the `@Test` method.

So your `DataProvider` method, simplofied for a single sample as in your question, should look like this:

```
@DataProvider(name = "browserProvider")
    public Object[][] getData() throws IOException {
        
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                "C:\\Users\\user\\git\\Quntrix-Training\\automation\\src\\test\\resources\\config.properties");
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(fis);

        Object[][] data = new Object[1][1];
        data[0][0] = p.getProperty("BrowserType");
        return data;
    }
```

And if in the `properties` there is more data, just iterate or retrieve as you need and keep filling the `Object[][]`.

Comment: So should I create a separate method, like .getfile() to parse the file then call it with another Object[][] method?

Comment: I'll update the answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried creating both the FileInputStream and Object[][] objects within the data provider but couldn't quite get it right. Arrays still throw me off a bit! This makes perfect sense though.

Comment: You are most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Despite the answer you have marked as correct solves your particular issue I would like to give some insight because I assume that you misunderstand the concept of data providers.

**Why does it return `Object[][]`?**

Data providers is a mechanism that allows to multiply a single test so that having that single test and `N` pieces of input data you would have `N` tests.

This is where `Object[][]` comes from. Basically `Object[][]` is an array of `Object[]` where "outer array" holds the sequences of parameters for different test and each sequence is represented by "inner array".

For example you have a method:

```java
public void testMyStuff(String a, String b){
   ...
}
```

**This method takes two arguments**, so that the "horizontal" size of your `Object[][]` would be **2**.

Now if you want to split this single test into three different tests you need to have "vertical" size of your `Object[][]` equal to **3**.

```java
Object[][] test = {
        {"A1", "B1"},
        {"A2", "B2"},
        {"A3", "B3"}
};
```

So that you would have the following execution sequence:

```java
testMyStuff("A1", "B1");
testMyStuff("A2", "B2");
testMyStuff("A3", "B3");
```

**So why is it not your case?**

You have a single property file where you have a single value for your property. This is not the pattern for data providers. It is better to poll property value straight from your test.